# What does the single quote ' mean?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation

I am studying the book "What is mathematics: an elementary approach to ideas and methods"
 and i came over a few equations that have the single quote notation in them, and i am not sure what it mean, or even if it means different things in different context.

Here is an image of what I mean:
[image: Here is an image of what i mean.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$a$ and $a'$ (*say $a$-prime*) are just two different variables. You will often find the notation used where $a'$ is related in some way to $a$ - it is a modified version of $a$, or comparable/similar in some other way.

If you see the $'$ prime mark used with a function, however, it should mean the derivative of that function: $f(x) = x^3$ and $f'(x)=3x^2$ etc, with the double prime being the second derivative, $f''(x) = 6x$.

Answer (score 5):

It has no special meaning here, you should just consider $a'$ being a different name from $a$ (and so possibly a different element). Another way would be writing $a_1$ and $a_2$, for example.

Comment: I would say $a'$ is a different **name** from $a$, but they can represent the same element.

Comment: That's good, thanks @adayah

Answer (score 0):

You could have "7)" instead of "1')" etc., but if you look, the primed versions are strongly related to the unprimed versions.

Comment: He was probably not talking about the numbering but about $a'$ and $b'$.